# 2 function share the same ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

function 1

```
ClassSignIn.prototype.Login = function ()
{
var postData = $("#x-form :input").serializeArray();

ClassAjax.ajaxFunction(postData);
}
```

function 2

```
ClassSignIn.prototype.RedirectLogin = function (_username, _password)
{
//how do i make my variable look like serializeArray(); and pass to ajax function ?

my code



  var loginData = [];

   loginData.push('login-name', _username);
   loginData.push('login-password', _password);

ClassAjax.ajaxFunction(loginData);
}
```

ajax function

```
ClassAjax.prototype.ajaxFunction = function (_data){

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/classlogin.php",
  data: _data,
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {

  }
  });

}
```

my intention to make 2 login function share the same ajax function but 2 of those login function pass in data differently , the 1st function pass in with serializeArray , the second one pass in variable.

the 1st function work , but the second one fail , how i can i make those 2 function share the same ajax ?

Comment: sorry i just mistype it , but the 1st function do work , my problem is how i going to pass the variable on second function ?

Comment: or i should just make 2 different ajax function ?

Answer (score 0):

subject to your backend deserializing of data.

**try**

change:

```
loginData.push('login-name', _username);
loginData.push('login-password', _password);
```

to:

```
loginData.push({'login-name': _username});
loginData.push({'login-password': _password});
```

**or**

change:

```
var loginData = []
loginData.push('login-name', _username);
loginData.push('login-password', _password);
```

to:

```
var loginData = {}
loginData['login-name'] = _username;
loginData['login-password'] = _password;
```

**EDIT:** to mirror serializeArray() function